# "Students soon!" - is this a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have to make an English title to a photo of children preparing to go to school for the first time. Is "Students soon!" a grammatical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, *Students soon!* sounds quite idiomatic.

Personally, I would use:

> **Future Students!**

**OR**

> **Soon to be students!**

Comment: You could say that if this is their first day of school, officially they are students already.

Comment: Thank you! At the moment the photo was taken they were officially still kindergarten children just eager to go to school.

Comment: Or 'Soon to be students.' (Though in British English we would probably say _schoolchildren_, as _students_ usually implies people in further or higher education.)

Comment: @KateBunting good suggestion added to post

Comment: Yes, really a good suggestion - thanks! Is it also correct to say "Soon to be PUPILS" in British English? This word is used for primary school children on UK government site, e.g.: "Statistics on pupils in schools in England as collected in the January 2018..." Though as far as I know "pupil" would sound a bit archaically nowadays even in the UK - would it?